# Use a std::bitset or a fundamental type of the same size?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, std-bitset

I'm creating a Chess Solver and have decided to use bitboards. Conveniently there are 64 squares on a standard chess board. This is nice since the prevalence of 64-bit operating systems a single bitboard can fit into a single register.

That said, are there fundamental differences (size (memory and code), speed, complexity, memory usage, etc) in using a `std::bitset<64>` and the functions therein or the fundamental type of the "same" size `unsigned long long` and performing the bit twiddling manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint64_t` probably. You'll want to perform operations that are not available on `std::bitset`, including almost all arithmetic operations, bitscan, using parts of the board as index into an array, and SSE intrinsics if you get serious about it.

For example (not an exhaustive list by any means, just some simple examples) in [o^(o-2r)](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Subtracting+a+Rook+from+a+Blocking+Piece) (and its [cousin](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Fill+by+Subtraction)), the more advanced Hyperbola Quintessence, as part of extracting the lowest set bit, etc.

You could use `std::bitset` but you'd be converting it back to some type of integer a lot.

Comment: You make some good points. Though, in Visual Studio at least, `uint64_t` is a typedef for `unsigned long long`, so when using `uint64_t` even though readability and comprehension for the reader increase, it makes no difference to the compiler or CPU.

Comment: The fixed-width types are literally there for readability and comprehension... not to mention so you know for sure what you're dealing with. Why would you pick `unsigned long long` over `uint64_t` when you want a 64-bit type?